# Finding the classpath for a dynamically supplied .class name

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am working in a very large application with an inordinate number of user defined classes in it.  I need to find the fully qualified class name for a .class file so that I can load it during runtime.

The name of the .class file is passed as a key value pair in a JSON Web Tokenized URL.  I decrypt to the token and capture the relevant parameters.  These parameters are an ID and a web class where the user is redirected.

```
Claims jwtVerified = bus.decryptJsonWebToken(token);
    if(jwtVerified != null){
        String Id = jwtVerified.get("ID").toString();
        String page = jwtVerified.get("page").toString();
        PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
        pageParameters.add("Id", Id);

        try {
            Class<Page> c = null;
            c = (Class<Page>) Class.forName("com.foo." + page);                         
            throw new RestartResponseException(c, pageParameters);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that I do not want to hard code "com.foo." because different pages can be passed as the page variable.  And these classes live in different packages (e.g., "com.foo.Myclass.class" vs "com.bar.MyClass2.class").  Moreover, if I do not supply the fully qualified classpath, then a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

Comment: "Classpath" and "fully qualified class name" are two different things.

Comment: You are right. I edited my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) package, but you would have to be sure that there are no two classes with the same name.

This code may be a good start:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.yourpackage", new SubTypesScanner());
final Collection<Class<? extends Page>> allTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Page.class);
final Map<String, Class<? extends Page>> shortNameToClass = new HashMap<>();
for (Class<? extends Page> type : allTypes) {
    shortNameToClass.put(type.getSimpleName(), type);
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Class<? extends Page>> entry : shortNameToClass.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "->" + entry.getValue());
}
```